# could not find or load main class.java

Tags: java, program-entry-point

I have two classes for function overloading in JAVA namely ABC and XYZ. XYZ class has the function overloading methods whereas ABC class has the main method. I have saved the file as ABC.java. The program do compiles but shows an error "could not find or load main class ABC" during runtime. I have also attached my code to be specific.

```
class XYZ
{
   void pqr(int a, int b)
   {
      int res = a*b;
      System.out.println("The result is "+res);
   }
   void pqr(String a, String b)
   {
     System.out.println("The concatenated string is "+a+b);
   }
   void pqr(int a, int b, int c)
{ 
int res = a+b+c;
    System.out.println("The final result is "+res);
}
}

class ABC

{
 public static void main(String[] args)
{
    XYZ a = new XYZ();
    a.pqr(10,20);
    a.pqr("Pratik","Paul");
    a.pqr(20, 40, 60);
 }

}
```

Comment: I think there are no errors

Comment: make the class `ABC` public

Comment: @Pratik: can you mention the folder path of these files. Also are you working in eclipse or notepad?

Comment: @Lathy: the path for these files is D:\Pratik\Java. Currently I am using notepad++ and compiling is done using javac

Comment: @sandip: I did but another error comes up which says "class ABC is public, should be declared in a file named ABC.java"

Comment: are these two classes defined in same .java file or different java file?

Comment: If both classes are saved in the same file and you have made ABC public,make sure to save the file as ABC.java. To compile execute the command: javac ABC.java and to run it execute the command: java ABC  .This should work

Comment: @Lathy: Both the classes are in the same java file and I have also did exactly as you said. But still there is an error coming up which says "class ABC is public, should be declared in a file named ABC.java"

Comment: move class ABC to new file named ABC.java

Comment: @Lathy: Tried this as well. I kept both the classes in different files and tried to compile it but still getting the error "could not find or load main class ABC"

Comment: Basically your problem is about classpath

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps,

Step1:

```
go the bin folder of Java from command prompt(I assume you are trying to run the program from command prompt).

ex: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin
```

Step2:

```
javac <your ABC.java file with full path>

ex: javac C:\Test\ABC.java

similary do for XYZ.java
```

Step3:

```
Go to C:\Test\ from command prompt and run,
java ABC
```

Comment: It should work. I posted exactly what I did. U are missing something. Stil you get could not load main class ABC?

Comment: Could you post me your code?Maybe I could compare and figure out whats wrong exactly. And one more thing that I have seen is that, There is no error when I write the main method within the same class XYZ. The problem occurs only when using different classes.

Comment: I think you might not have set the classpath

Comment: Go to Environment variables->System Variables-> new -> variable: CLASSPATH. value : your class file directory and compile the ABC file. It should compile then run it

Comment: This is the beauty of having IDE.. Its like you are fighting the war without a sword. The IDE will take care of setting the classpaths..